# why flutter web_view showing error on initial Url?

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I install the web_view flutter plugin and set minTargetSDk to 20 but still, I face an error on initialurl.
Here is the code snippet:
[image]

Comment: So what **is** the error?

Comment: Please post your error more in details.

Comment: actually, I am showing the website in the application. but HTTP website gives me an error and HTTPS websites are working well.

Comment: Post your console error as well

Comment: W/ample.fixit_ap(14976): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/DecorView(14976): createDecorCaptionView windowingMode:1 mWindowMode 1 isFullscreen: true
W/cr_media(14976): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
I/ample.fixit_ap(14976): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=707 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
W/ContentCatcher(14976): Failed to notify a WebView

Comment: Please post the error in question it self, so that it will ease developer to read. Edit you question and add the error at last.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change you page name from WebView to any other.
Or you can do it as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart' as wv;

class WebView extends StatefulWidget {
   const WebView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   State<WebView> createState() => _WebViewState();
}

class _WebViewState extends State<WebView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return wv.WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev/',
    );
  }
}
```